# using perl insert string xml to a node

Tags: xml, perl

I have the following xml as a string in a variable $myXML and need to insert it inside root->grouping

```
<mydata seq="ee">
    <subdata name="bla" value="bla" />
</mydata>
```

The above xml needs to be inserted inside root->grouping

```
<root>
  <grouping>    
  </grouping>
</root>
```

I am currently using XML::Twig so ideally if you could help me using that

**edit:**
I'm dealing with a complex < root > structure that resides in a file. I need a way to load that < root > xml into perl and insert my xml string as a node. Also in my case < grouping > already has some nodes inside it.

Comment: So, in which place exactly you trying to insert the `$myxml` string .. since you said you already have other nodes inside <Grouping>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it: I would create an element from the XML in `$myXML`, then add it as the last child of `grouping`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $myXML='<mydata seq="ee"><subdata name="bla" value="bla" /></mydata>';

my $t= XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { grouping => sub { grouping( $myXML, @_); }, })
                ->parsefile( "so_insert.xml");

$t->print;
exit;

sub grouping
  { my( $xml, $t, $grouping)= @_;
    my $new_elt= XML::Twig::Elt->parse( $xml);
    $new_elt->paste( last_child => $grouping);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a twig handler to insert content upon seeing the grouping tag.

Assuming your root/grouping data is in `foo.xml`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $myXML = <<'EOT';
<mydata seq="ee">
    <subdata name="bla" value="bla" />
</mydata>
EOT

my $xml = XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print => 'indented',
    twig_handlers => {
        grouping => sub { $_->set_text($myXML)->set_asis; }
    });

$xml->parsefile("foo.xml") or die "Failed parse of foo.xml: $@\n";
$xml->print;
```

Comment: Thanks alot Mark, that partially works but it's overwriting whatever data I already have in "grouping" while I need to append it.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something?

```
$myXML = '<root><grouping>' . $myXML . '</grouping></root>';
```

Comment: I'm dealing with a complex <root> structure that resides in a file. I need a way to load that <root> xml into perl and insert my xml string as a node. Also in my case <grouping> already has some nodes inside it.

Comment: Ah ok, you should state that in the question... :)