# How to add node to a XML file using perl XML::Twig

Tags: xml, perl

I need to add a node to a already existing xml file,my xml is like:-

```
<Install>
  <version >
    <number>6.1</number>
    <build>1025654</build>
    <path>path</path>
    <kind>RIBS</kind>
  </version>
</Install>
```

and after adding node it should look like

```
<Install>
  <version >
    <number>6.1</number>
    <build>1025654</build>
    <path>path</path>
    <kind>native</kind>
  </version>
  <version >
    <number>6.0</number>
    <build>1025786</build>
    <path>path</path>
    <kind>native</kind>
  </version>
</Install>
```

I tried the idea from following link but was not able to figure it out.
[using perl insert string xml to a node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471954/using-perl-insert-string-xml-to-a-node)

I need to add the node and save the changes to the file.
It should be reflected into the file.
I am new to perl that why not able to figure it out.

What I tried is :-

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $myXML
  ='<version>6.1</version>
    <number>101445</number>
    <path>path</path>
    <kind>native</kind>
   ';
my $file = "C:\\Users\\bjoshi\\LightroomBuilds\\Win\\data.xml";
my $t= XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { grouping => sub { grouping( $myXML, @_); }, })
                ->parsefile( "$file") or die $!;

$t->print;
open my $xml_fh, '>', "$file" or die $!;
$t->set_pretty_print('indented_c');
$t->print($xml_fh);
exit;

sub grouping
  { my( $xml, $t, $grouping)= @_;
    my $new_elt= XML::Twig::Elt->parse( $xml);
    $new_elt->paste( last_child => $grouping);
  }
```

The output which I an getting is:-

```
<Install>
  <version>
    <number>6.1</number>
    <build>1025654</build>
    <path>path</path>
    <kind>native</kind>
  </version>
</Install>
```

Comment: Please show what you have already tried. [Edit] your question and put the code that you wrote with the help of the answer you linked. It looks like the answer should work for you.

Comment: @simbabque I have edited the ques added my code there.

Comment: Your `$myXML` is not correct. Compare the expected output you gave to what you have done. The elements are not nested correctly.

Comment: @simbabque I have updated $myXML but is not getting updated to the xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the code [from the linked answer by mirod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6484016/1331451) did the same thing you wanted to do, you need to adjust it to fit your XML. I'll explain below what I did.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $myXML = <<'XML';
<version>
  <number>6.0</number>
  <build>1025786</build>
  <path>path</path>
  <kind>native</kind>
</version>
XML

my $t = XML::Twig->new(
  twig_handlers => {
    Install => sub { add_version( $myXML, @_ ); }, }
  )->parse( \*DATA ) or die $!;

$t->set_pretty_print('indented_c');
$t->print;

sub add_version {
    my ( $xml, $t, $install ) = @_;
    my $new_elt = XML::Twig::Elt->parse($xml);
    $new_elt->paste( last_child => $install );
}

__DATA__
<Install>
  <version >
    <number>6.1</number>
    <build>1025654</build>
    <path>path</path>
    <kind>RIBS</kind>
  </version>
</Install>
```

This will read not from a file but from the `DATA` file handle that takes the stuff below `__DATA__`, and just print to the terminal/screen.

First of all, your expected output was like this:

```
<Install>
  ...
  <version>
    <number>6.0</number>
    ...
  </version>
</Install>
```

But the piece of XML to insert that you used in your code is like this:

```
<version>6.1</version>
<number>101445</number>
...
```

That's not what you said you wanted, so I guess that is a mistake.

The code you took from the answer was supposed to work for an element `<grouping>`. In principle it's the same, but it has a different name. So you need to adapt the code. I changed the `twig_handlers` to have a handler for `Install` because that is the root element of your XML. I went on to rename the subroutine and the variables inside to match that. It makes it more clear what's going on.

If you run it, you get this output:

```
<Install>
  <version>
    <number>6.1</number>
    <build>1025654</build>
    <path>path</path>
    <kind>RIBS</kind>
  </version>
  <version>
    <number>6.0</number>
    <build>1025786</build>
    <path>path</path>
    <kind>native</kind>
  </version>
</Install>
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there is a way to use variable inside $myXML??

Comment: If you use double quotes it will interpolate variables. If that is new for you, I suggest to get some perl book. The tag wiki has an excellent list of free resources and book recommendations :-)